# PHPMailer MySQLi multiple email addresses

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

I am at the end of my rope and would really really appreciate any help you could spare...

I have the following code and although it works on an individual basis, I can for the life of me not make it work so that all email addresses are sent at the same time using PHPMailer.

I have scoured StackOverflow for the past few months, trying an exhaustive amount of combinations without success.
There are a number of discussions on this forum and although I have tried all the solutions on here, I can still not make it work. If I offend anyone by potentially duplicating the question, please accept my apologies in advance.

```
<?php 

// Script Error Reporting
//error_reporting(0);

    // Require the form_functions to process the form
    require('databaseConnect.php');

    // Require the Email Class Functions
    require("mailApp/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("mailApp/class.smtp.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive=true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->setFrom("No_Reply@girrawaagames.com", "Girrawaa Games"); // Valid email address from sender and Company name. Only Company name will be displayed

$mail->Subject='CASH Trader | The Spirit Stone'; // This adds the subject title in the subject line field

    // Create a connection to MySQL and the database:
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check if the connection is active:
    if(!$con) {
        header('Location: alternate.php'); 
        }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fname, email FROM emails WHERE condition = 'condition'");

/* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $user['fname'][] = $row["fname"];
        $user['email'][] = $row["email"];
        }

    $mail->AddAddress($user['email']);

$mail->Body="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
<title>CASH Trader</title>
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" />

</head>

<body yahoo bgcolor=\"#ccffff\" style=\"margin:0; padding-top:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px;\">
                            <table align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style=\"padding-top:20px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-left:0px; color:#153643; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">
                                    <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class=\"header\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px; color:#153643; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">
                                            <a href=\"http://www.girrawaagames.com\"><img src=\"http://www.girrawaagames.com/img/logo.jpg\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF\" alt=\"Cash Trader Logo\" style=\"display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto;\" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" style=\"padding-top:40px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:30px;\">
                                        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align=\"center\" style=\"color:#153643; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px;\">
                                                <b>Hi " . $user['fname'] . "</b>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                            </table>

</body>
</html>";

print_r($user['fname']);
print_r($user['email']);

    if ($mail->send()) {
        $updateCampaign = "UPDATE emails SET column = 'value' WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($row['email']) . "'";
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $updateCampaign);
        }

        // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
        $mail->clearAddresses();

        mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What have you got when you echo $addr?

Comment: Do you want to send one email to 50 recipients? Or 50 emails individually to 50 recipients? If the former check the body message, using `userFName`. If the latter wrap mail objects in the database resultset loop.

Comment: Hi Richard, I get the last email address on the list. As I update the database each time an email is used, it finds the next available email to use.

Comment: Hi Parfait, 50 to 50, and that is where I am getting unstuck.

Comment: Probably you want to discover the **addCc** and **addBcc** PHPMailer's functions. These will allow you to send the same message to multiple recipients and avoiding (mostly in the addBcc one) displaying everybodies email addresses in every email that gets delivered.

Comment: I can also see you are neither initializing the $user and $user['email'] and $user['fname'] keys before you use them. That would be a good idea I guess. I'm also not seeing SMTP credentials being set. Is your server automatically set to deliver email through some SMTP?

Comment: Yes, I have set the parameters in either SMTP or PHPMailer classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `$useremail` for it to have multiple emails.

```
 $userEmail = '';
 foreach($rows as $row) {
            $userFname = $row["fname"];
            $userEmail .= $row["email"] . ',';
 }
```

It would probably be easier to pair these in an array..

```
 foreach($rows as $row) {
            $user['fname'][] = $row["fname"];
            $user['email'][] = $row["email"];
 }
```

Then you don't need the `explode` function later.

....

or better yet set it in the `while` loop, dont need `foreach` at all.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     $user['fname'][] = $row["fname"];
     $user['email'][] = $row["email"];
}
```

Update:

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
//error_reporting(0);
// Require the form_functions to process the form
require('databaseConnect.php');
// Require the Email Class Functions
require("mailApp/class.phpmailer.php");
require("mailApp/class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive=true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->setFrom("No_Reply@girrawaagames.com", "Girrawaa Games"); // Valid email address from sender and Company name. Only Company name will be displayed
$mail->Subject='CASH Trader | The Spirit Stone'; // This adds the subject title in the subject line field
// Create a connection to MySQL and the database:
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
// Check if the connection is active:
if(!$con) {
    header('Location: alternate.php'); 
    exit();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fname, email FROM emails WHERE condition = 'condition'");
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $user['fname'][] = $row["fname"];
    $user['email'][] = $row["email"];
}
foreach($user['email'] as $key => $email) {
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Body="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
<title>CASH Trader</title>
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" />

</head>

<body yahoo bgcolor=\"#ccffff\" style=\"margin:0; padding-top:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px;\">
                            <table align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style=\"padding-top:20px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-left:0px; color:#153643; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">
                                    <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class=\"header\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px; color:#153643; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">
                                            <a href=\"http://www.girrawaagames.com\"><img src=\"http://www.girrawaagames.com/img/logo.jpg\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF\" alt=\"Cash Trader Logo\" style=\"display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto;\" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" style=\"padding-top:40px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:30px;\">
                                        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align=\"center\" style=\"color:#153643; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px;\">
                                                <b>Hi " . $user['fname'][$key] . "</b>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                            </table>

</body>
</html>";
    if ($mail->send()) {
        $updateCampaign = "UPDATE emails SET column = 'value' WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($row['email']) . "'";
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $updateCampaign);
    }
    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
     $mail->clearAddresses();
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris,I will try this when I get home. Reason I had explode is to issue emails to recipients individually. Perhaps your recommendation already does that, so I will try. Thank you

Comment: No it doesn't. I have tried above examples without errors or emails and it must boil down to my inexperience. I will keep working on it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Is this not storing each email address separately?

Comment: Hi Chris, finally succeeded in making it work. I used part of your answer and the code recommended by Synchro and ... Voila... an email to each recipient without each one knowing the email of the others. Thank you very much folks, I could not have done it without the both of you. Answer code below. It may not be pitch perfect but it does work.....

Comment: I have now come unstuck on the $userFname in the email body. The email address iterates without issue yet the recipient's first name is always the last name on the loop's list for all emails. What am I doing wrong here???  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fname, email FROM emails WHERE condition = 'condition' LIMIT 50");
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
 $userNames .= $row["fname"] . ',';
      $userEmail .= $row["email"] . ',';
 }
 $userFname = explode(',',$userNames);
 $addr = explode(',',$userEmail);
 foreach($addr as $ad) {
 $mail->AddAddress($ad);

Comment: Dunno. Is the code in the question above up to date?

Comment: Wow, lightning fast.... I could not get all the code on the comment so had to select what I think is the problem. Sorry but have been trying now since Friday to get this right.

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question and add the code in there.

Comment: I'd go option 3 rather than 1 from my answer you won't need explodes.

Comment: Can't see where my updated comments are...At this stage no email, no first name of recipient and no update to DB. I have tried a number of variations in location of code within the file. What am I missing here? Also, the result is 2 arrays, one for 'fname' and one for 'email'.

Comment: Update written. Note the iteration, `foreach($user['email'] $key => $email) {` this is how the values are parsed out of the array.

Comment: Received a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE' in the foreach line.Should I be declaring the variable $email?

Comment: Opps forgot `as` one sec..ha i even put it wrong in comment too. There needed(s) to be an `as` between the array the value each array value is going to. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Should be (??) correct now.

Comment: I could cry.... It works like a sweater on a clod night... Thank you so much. Some errors thrown up but I can work on them. You have no idea how long I have been working on this .... thank you

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've looked everywhere... apart from code you already have! There is [a mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that does exactly what you ask, correctly and efficiently.

In your code you're trying to send one message to 50 people, not 50 to 50, and it would also expose all addresses to all recipients, so this is generally a bad idea.

You've based your code on an obsolete example and are probably using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hi Synchro, I have tried modifying and implementing the code on your link and as with Chris' examples, I feel it must be my inexerience at play here. I do appreciate all your help and will keep trying to make it work.